# How does the equation of time period of a simple pendulum change in a very high gravitational field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, classical-mechanics, time-dilation

I want to calculate the time period of oscillation of a simple pendulum in a planet with a very high gravity. In classical mechanics where time is absolute, the time period of a simple pendulum is $$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$$
Where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. But in relativistic mechanics, we know that time is not absolute. So how will this change the equation of time period of simple pendulum?

Answer (score 0):

*T* is in the frame of reference of the pendulum so the formula stands. If you want to compare different time dilations in different frames of reference that could be a different matter.